# MapView tiles loading in Android

Tags: android, maps, android-mapview

In the Maps application (at least version 5) for Android the tiles are loading in a different way, than when using a MapView in my own application, when for example zooming in or out. In the MapView displays a gray checkered image until the tile is fully loaded an than the map is displayed. In Maps application this it not the case all the time. Tiles that are not fully loaded are still showing a map but it is blurry. The Maps application way of showing the map when zooming is much prettier for the eye.

Is it possible to have this "feature" in a MapView in my own application as well?

Best regards

P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the API that you're given tends to lag behind the one in use by the maps application. They may or may not add those changes to the public API, but it usually takes quite a while if they do. For example, we still can't access the topo map layer...

Answer (score 0):

I am still finding this issue is valid. Especially over 3G! I know that the Google Maps App Caches its tiles (and we can't as its against Googles T&C's) so thats not a great comparison, however its the comparison that people will be making!

I have used the function :

```
    mv.preLoad();
```

To tell the map to load the central tile first, however this still makes little difference to the time it takes to render onscreen tiles.

Has anyone come up with a decent solution (not looking at going to offline maps as of yet) or work around to make the tiles load faster over 3G?